# Ember.js Handlebars globalization approach

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to use ember.js in my Rails app.

Have a question specific to globalizing the handlerbars view template content.

Should I try to create myview.handlebars.erb and get the strings translated on the server side (havent tried this)  or should I create seperate handlebars templates per each language (doesnt sound like really DRY unless there is a cleaner way)?

Whats the ideal way to go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ember-I18n provides a solution: https://github.com/jamesarosen/ember-i18n

Comment: This is a problematic approach as you end with a template full of strings like this "user.followers.title.other" that are meaningless. In the template should be written this: 'All {{count}} Followers' so you can understand what are you laying out. Better wrap Jed.js or other gettext solution in a helper.

Answer (score 6):

Did you get this working to your satisfactioin?

Another alternative (what we use at http://travis-ci.org) is i18n-js.
We like it because it lets you keep all your localizations in the same place (config/locales/[x].yml) and automatically adds them into your assets path.

Part of that DRY thing ;)

The syntax in your handlebars is pretty much the same, we just us a handlebars helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('i18n', function(key) {
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(I18n.t(key))
});
```

and then {{i18n "path.to.translation"}} in the handlebars view.

Comment: Problematic solution too as flagged in the other answer.

Comment: I would like to use this inside of a `{{bindAttr ... title="i18n 'path.to.translation'" }}` scope, how do I do that?